# Format text for multiple elements using ZeroClipboard?

Tags: jquery, flash, copy-paste, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to use ZeroClipboard to copy and format two elements for line breaks on a page using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('#d_clip_button1, #d_clip_button2'), {
            moviePath: "/img/ZeroClipboard.swf"
            } );

        clip.on("dataRequested", function (client, args) {

        var txt = $('#copy_1, #copy_2').html();

        var windowsText = txt.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');

        windowsText = windowsText.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, "\r\n");

        client.setText(windowsText);

        });

        clip.on( "load", function(client) {

        client.on( "complete", function(client, args) {
        // `this` is the element that was clicked

        alert("Copied to clipboard: " );
    });
  });
});                     
</script>
```

The text in my `<pre id="copy_1">blah blah blah</pre>` gets formatted ok.

However, my other element `<pre id="copy_2">blah blah blah no. 2</pre>` outputs the text from `id="copy_1"`

How do i get both elements to format correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Greene (https://github.com/JamesMGreene) came up with the [answer](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/52):

Your line:

```
var txt = $('#copy_1, #copy_2').html();
```

Will always only return the innerHTML of the element with the ID "copy_1" as [jQuery's html() method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html) is only performed on the first returned element in the set:

> In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any
>   element. If the selector expression matches more than one element,
>   only the first match will have its HTML content returned.

Assuming your #d_clip_button[1/2] glued elements correspond to the #copy_[1/2] elements, you could do something like the following:

```
clip.on("dataRequested", function(client, args) {
  var txt, windowsText,
      targetId = this.getAttribute("data-clipboard-target"),
      targetEl = !targetId ? null : document.getElementById(targetId);
  if (targetEl) {
    txt = $(targetEl).html();
    windowsText = txt.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
    windowsText = windowsText.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, "\r\n");
    client.setText(windowsText);
  }
});
```